# Wordpress Codeigniter Integration: How to replace site_url on CI?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have some problem with URL of Wordpress and Codeigniter integration, because I want to avoid data collisions between WP and CI site_url.

Here is my code on CI : 
config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mydomain.com';
```

my_helper.php

```
add_filter('site_url', 'ci_site_url', 1);
function ci_site_url()
{
    include(APPPATH.'/config/config.php');
    return $config['base_url'];
}
```

It works fine and show http://www.domain.com when I use

```
<?php
echo site_url();
?>
```

I want http://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/xxx when I use site_url('admin/xxx');

I have been looking for an answer here but I can't find it, so I would thank any help on this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing wordpress and codeigniter is just a piece of cake. you need to do the following.
I assume you need wordpress inside Codeigniter so here is how you can do it.

in wordpress directory create a folder called myci

```
wordpress/
         /myci
```

Now put codeigniter package in myci. Next you need to add this statment to `index.php`

```
myci/
    /system
    /application
    /index.php

require_once('../wp-load.php');
```

Now you need to extend `site_url` and `base_url` like this

```
if (!function_exists('ci_site_url')) {
    function ci_site_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->site_url($uri);
    }
}
if (!function_exists('ci_base_url')) {
    function ci_base_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->base_url($uri);
    }
}
```

How to use :

Now you can access it like this. Hope it helps

```
http://www.domain.com/myci/index.php/controllername/method
```

Note folder name before index.php

Comment: Is there somewhere better to put the if statements, other than in the root index.php? A core folder or library?

Comment: @Luke i said you need to extend the helper. So this code will be written in the the my_url_helper.php and will be saved in `application/helpers` directory

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything that needs to be done to ensure that my_url_helper.php gets loaded?

Comment: No you can simply call it in controller to check if it is working fine. It is autoloaded. You dont need to worry

Answer (score 0):

@raheel shan
Where to add :

```
if (!function_exists('ci_site_url')) {
function ci_site_url($uri = '')
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->config->site_url($uri);
}
}
if (!function_exists('ci_base_url')) {
function ci_base_url($uri = '')
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->config->base_url($uri);
}
}
```