# WordPress and CodeIgniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter-2

I have codeigniter application, and I would like to use WordPress just for blog.

So for example. http://www.myapp.com is codeigniter, and http://www.myapp.com/blog will be wordpress, I do not want to explain why I want to use wp, it is just the best... :) So when ever users visits /blog I need to use wp functions to display posts, some other data..., also when user from ci site go to blog, I will automatically login them to wp.

This is how currently everything is structured for now.

```
/public_html/index.php - ci file - root folder
ci_app - is not at root folder, is one folder upper
ci_sys - is not at root folder, is one folder upper
wp_blog - wp folder is also one folder upper
```

[image]

I have google it for 2 days, tried a lot of stuff.

At first place this :

```
require_once realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/wp/wp-load.php';
require_once BASEPATH . 'core/CodeIgniter' . EXT;
```

Then follow these steps : http://www.marketingadept.com/blog/2013/02/integrating-codeigniter-and-wordpress/

revert back several times....

Usually I get redirect loop problem. or 500 error when editing htaccess files.

Really need help with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920691/wordpress-codeigniter-integration-how-to-replace-site-url-on-ci/19925523#19925523) may help you.

Comment: @raheelshan Hi, thank you for response, in my case CI and WP could be on same level or WP to be level bellow CI, but not CI to be in WP. :(

Comment: why are you verbally describing your folder structure? just show directory tree...

Comment: @Jakub I have describe folder structure in a question.

Comment: And here is screen shoot http://i42.tinypic.com/2mdq4u9.png